# Format the mobile From WM6 to WM7

Tags: windows-mobile

I have `HTC Touch HD` Phone, whith `windows mobile 6.1`, How can i change to `Windows mobile 7` ?

Thank you

Comment: Except HTC HD2, no other WM devices can install WP7

Answer (score 5):

No, this is **not** possible.

Windows Phone 7 and 8 are completely different to Windows Mobile and require very different, more powerful hardware.